# OAuth with Google on Android 12 gives me invalid_grant, but succeeds on Android 11

Tags: android, react-native, oauth, google-oauth

I'm using the same credentials the client has on web for Google to OAuth on Android, and it works flawlessly on Android 11. With Android 12, I have validated the domain name with the certificate, and deep linking works properly. I can login with other OAuth sources fine and get the callbacks to the app no problem. However, with Google, it consistently returns `invalid_grant`, no matter what certificate I use. I've even done an internal test using the Play certificate, and I also get `invalid_grant` (and the domain is verified on that build as well.)

The message on Android 12 is just "Bad request."

I'm using https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth for authentication.

This also works fine on iOS and Android 11 as well... Thanks for your time!

Comment: Seems weird to me.  I sent a ping out to the team, I cant promise a response.

Comment: maybe related to this: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/462

Comment: @ZigMandel yes this seems like it at the end...  but still unresolved.

Comment: that github issue gives a workaround @ewindsor

Comment: @ewindsor did you try this specific steps? https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/462#issuecomment-1144420956